# Javascript regex selecting numbers that are not connected to letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, format

This is my current regex:

```
var re = '/\d+\s+[\d+a-z]+/gi';
```

I'm trying to get my regex to select numbers before if there are there own and then any abc characters and numbers after a whitespace

This is my test string

```
part1 6

22 part2

part3 8
```

At the moment its selecting the following

```
1 : 6

22 part2

3 8
```

But I just want to be selecting this

```
22 part2
```

So i'm only wanting to select this if the number is on its own.

Any help thanks ?

Comment: Try [`var re = /\b\d+\s+[\da-z]+/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/tGOaC7/1). Note that if the text is a multiline string, you'd better replace `\s` with `[ \t]`, or a mere space.

Comment: Use: `/\b\d+\s+[a-z]+\d+\b/ig`

Comment: just updated to javascript been using the [regular expressions tool](https://regex101.com/r/doep18/1/)

Comment: Just what i was looking for thanks

Answer (score 0):

The regex is `/^\d+\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`

- `^` start
- `\d+\s` 1 or more digits and 1 space
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` the alpha numeric combination
- `$` end

```js
var arr=["part1 6","22 part2","part3 8"];

var re=/^\d+\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

arr.forEach(x => console.log(x,re.test(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this regex

```
regex : /^\d+\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s\d+$;
```